# Is binary the most regular "format" an image can be converted to?

Tags: python, image, binary, python-imaging-library

I am making an application which is supposed to detect gray digits on an either a black background with varying tones or rgb(184, 180, 152).

Example date: [image: The tricky date]
Example digit image which is cut from the menu 4x8 with only grey color: [image: Example integer]

While the montone background allowed for a simple `Image.open(...).tobytes.index(Image.open(<filepath to digit>).tobytes())` to check if given digit was in the image, since every background remains the same, the "varying" background has a different color pattern for each digit's non-gray pixels in the 4x8 space. Getting a seperate file for each line's all 10 digits would take so much time and most likely render my application very slow.

The irregular return values provided by `.tobytes()` method made it practically impossible (to my knowledge at least) to apply a RegEx to fill the blank pixels with any arbitrary color and that way checking solely the gray areas.
**My desired converted data "format" of the images would be one in which each pixel corresponds to its own sequence of characthers.**

For example a color corresponding to `blank, blank, gray` would become `000000001040` once converted from its `Image.open(...)`-form where `0000`is the "blank". That way I could apply a RegEx from the returned string which would fill the blanks with any arbitrary color. That way only the grey will be check as opposed to also controlling non-gray colors inside the 4x8 area. What I get using `.tobytes()` rather corresponds to `1123999938212`; the pattern seems to change whenever a pixel is added and therefore unpredictable.

However, I suspect that this is the fault of `tobytes()` and that binary can fullfill my need of obtaining a sequence representing each pixel. If this is right, how can I convert the image to a **binary sequence** to use as a string?

**Note:** When I say "format" I am not meaning extention, **instead data "formats" such as binary, hex or XML.**

I am hestiant to use OpenCV since it might be an overkill that will make the application- which will scan through several images- slower. In lack of a better solution I will opt for it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your broader question is? Are you trying _to fill the blank pixels with any arbitrary color_?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Are you hoping to find a suitable file format for something? Or do template matching? Or an Otsu thresholding? Or regex matching? Why do you think using the most highly optimised software around will slow you down?

Comment: What I wished from `Image..tobytes()` (demonstratory value, not something I have actually got) : blank, grey, grey -> 000010401040 where 0000 corresponds to blank which I can easily make correspond  to any arbitrary value. What I instead got was, let's say 02305221321, which showed no pattern and was therefore uncompatible with RegEx. However, if I can find the "format" (in lack for a better word) there won't simply be any need to use OpenCV to analyse meager 4x8 digits.

Comment: You can't detect digits in an image using a regex on the pixel brightnesses - it will not work if the image is or has ever been saved as a JPEG, if there is any noise, if the image has been contrast-adjusted, or if the image has been cropped out of a larger one - or any number of other things. So the answer to your question is that an image is the best format for an image and image processing is the best method for understanding its content - not regex matching. Please go back a step and say what you currently have and what you actually want to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Binary is not an image format. Calling binary an image format is like calling sound a language.

Comment: I do not want to ** save the image as binary** , but I want to ** obtain the image's binary value** as a string.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, PIL already provides a method perfect for my need.

The entire image can be converted to a list of tuples containing each respective pixel's RGBA using: `list((Image.open(...).getdata())`, where `(255,255,255, 0)` is a blank pixel.